# bibliography not aligned in latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, biblatex

I tried to add bibliography in Latex with a bibtex file and not all of the sources are aligned. As you can see, the first ones are alright but the last ones look    something like this and I don't know why.

[image]

This is what I have in my bibliography.bib file that I included:

```
@article{isinkaye2015recommendation,
  title={Recommendation systems: Principles, methods and evaluation},
  author={Isinkaye, Folasade Olubusola and Folajimi, Yetunde O and Ojokoh, Bolande Adefowoke},
  journal={Egyptian informatics journal},
  volume={16},
  number={3},
  pages={261--273},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{berka2004designing,
  title={Designing recommender systems for tourism},
  author={Berka, Tobias and Pl{\"o}{\ss}nig, Manuela},
  journal={Proceedings of ENTER 2004},
  volume={11},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Citeseer}
}

@article{bouraga2014knowledge,
  title={Knowledge-based recommendation systems: A survey},
  author={Bouraga, Sarah and Jureta, Ivan and Faulkner, St{\'e}phane and Herssens, Caroline},
  journal={International Journal of Intelligent Information Technologies (IJIIT)},
  volume={10},
  number={2},
  pages={1--19},
  year={2014},
  publisher={IGI Global}
}

 @misc{turchenko_2021, title={Airbnb vs. Booking.com: Pros and Cons for the host}, url={https://payspacemagazine.com/tech/airbnb-vs-booking-com-pros-cons-for-the-host/}, journal={PaySpace Magazine}, publisher={PaySpaceMagazine}, author={Turchenko, Alina}, year={2021}, month={Aug}} 

@phdthesis{ahmed2017interactive,
  title={An interactive knowledge based recommender system for tourism},
  author={Ahmed, Wakil and Nur, Farah and Hema, Nabila Bhuyan and Ahmed, Nasim and others},
  year={2017},
  school={BRAC University}
}

@inproceedings{delgado2002knowledge,
  title={Knowledge bases and user profiling in travel and hospitality recommender systems},
  author={Delgado, Joaquin and Davidson, Richard},
  booktitle={ENTER},
  pages={1--16},
  year={2002},
  organization={Citeseer}
}

@inproceedings{grbovic2018real,
  title={Real-time personalization using embeddings for search ranking at airbnb},
  author={Grbovic, Mihajlo and Cheng, Haibin},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 24th ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery \& Data Mining},
  pages={311--320},
  year={2018}
}

@misc{howairbnbnworks,
  author       = "",
  title        = "Pros and Cons of Using Airbnb",
  howpublished = "https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/032814/pros-and-cons-using-airbnb.asp",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{booking,
  author       = "",
  title        = "booking.com: cea mai mare selecție de hoteluri, case și apartamente de vacanță",
  howpublished = "https://www.booking.com/content/about.ro.html",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{trip,
  author       = "",
  title        = "How TripAdvisor Changed Travel",
  howpublished = "https://www.theguardian.com/news/2018/aug/17/how-tripadvisor-changed-travel",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{js,
  author       = "",
  title        = "JavaScript",
  howpublished = "https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{react,
  author       = "",
  title        = "React",
  howpublished = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{reactjs,
  author       = "",
  title        = "Reasons to Choose React.js for Your Web Development Project",
  howpublished = "https://www.peerbits.com/blog/reasons-to-choose-reactjs-for-your-web-development-project.html",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{expressjs,
  author       = "",
  title        = "What Is Express.js",
  howpublished = "https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/nodejs-tutorial/what-is-express-js",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{reactjss,
  author       = "",
  title        = "React.js",
  howpublished = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_overview.htm",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{mysql,
  author       = "",
  title        = "What Is MySQL",
  howpublished = "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/what-is-mysql.html",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}

@misc{mvc,
  author       = "",
  title        = "Everything You Need To Know About MVC Architecture",
  howpublished = "https://towardsdatascience.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-mvc-architecture-3c827930b4c1",
  month        = "",
  year         = "2022",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}
```

My deadline is tomorrow and I've been trying to find a solution since yesterday, so if you could help me I would be extremely thankful!

Comment: In your @misc{react} you need a backslash \ before the underscores _. I'm not sure that will fix the problem, but it might :)

Comment: Not really a programming question. Try replacing the underscores in the URLs with `%95`

Comment: Hi! Adding your main file (minimal) code would be useful.

Comment: Many modern bibliography styles support a dedicated field for URLs (usually called `url`) where special characters need not be escaped. If you use a "normal" field like `howpublished`, you need to wrap the URLs in a command like `\url{...}` (the preferable option) or escape the special characters (not preferable for URLs).

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't set urls as normal text. Special characters like `_` will cause errors.

Instead you can use the `url` or `hyperref` package and mark the url with `\url{...}`